# API works with token when called in chrome, but does not work with the same token when called from my code

Tags: java, api, https

I am trying to make an API call to get data from Navitia.

The URL looks like this :

```
https://{myToken}@api.navitia.io/v1/journeys?from={...}
```

When I copy paste the complete URL in a private tab browser it works fine, but when I call the API from my code I get a 401 error.

This is the code to call the API :

```
String sURL = "https://{myToken}@api.navitia.io/v1/journeys?from=" +longDeparture +";" + latDeparture + "&to="+ longArrival+ ";"+latArrival +"&";
URL url = new URL(sURL);

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.connect();

int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponseCode: " + responseCode);
} else {...}
```

But it works here when copy pasting :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyodp.png)

Comment: The URL is missing a 2nd slash after https: in the code snippet you provided. Is it missing in your real code as well?

Comment: @fbastien It is not missing, this is a mistake when replacing my token by « {myToken} »

Comment: @Fadi HTTP 401 is an authorization/authentication error. This may be due to your browser unnoticeably sending some auth data that your script doesn't, or the API provider having some script protection. Can you check the `WWW-Authenticate` header(s) in the response you get? It should indicate how to authenticate. You should be able to retrieve headers with `conn.getHeaderFields()` or `conn.getHeaderField("WWW-Authenticate")`

Comment: @starball thank you ! :) Also, thank you for your help, i finally found a solution before I saw your response.

Comment: @fbastien thank you for your help and you clarification. I found a solution to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I stopped calling the API from the Java code.
What I do know is I create a process to curl the api from the terminal and I just fetch the output. I guess it's not the best solution but it works fine now.